# Is this quantity nonnegative?

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1,x_2, y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb R$.

Is $$x_1^2 x_2^2 - x_1^2 y_2^2 + 4 x_1 x_2 y_1 y_2 - x_2^2 y_1^2 + y_1^2 y_2^2 \geq 0 ? $$

Comment: $x_1=y_2=0$, $x_2=y_1=1$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: that's an answer. Pretty much.

Comment: You can rewrite your expression as $$(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)^2-(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2\geq0$$ to illuminate what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot say that it is non-negative, and you cannot say it is non-positive.

For example, if $x_1=y_2=0$ and $x_2=y_1=1$, then the expression is negative.

If $y_1=y_2=0$ and $x_1=x_2=1$, then it is positive.

Here is a useful fact: A polynomial with real coefficients is non-negative iff it can be written as a sum of squares of rational functions with real coefficients. This suggests a clear approach: Try to write your expression as sum of squares. This is Hilbert's 17th problem. (In general, we shouldn't expect a sum of squares of polynomials. I wrote a [blog post](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/275-positive-polynomials/) a while ago illustrating this.)

As Mark pointed out in the comments, trying to rewrite your expression as a combinatioon of squares gives us $(x_1x_2+2y_1y_2)^2-(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2$, and it is clear from this that the expression takes both positive and negative values.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll accept this in 3 minutes.